# Adjust Firefox and Thunderbird to a High DPI touchscreen display (retina)

Tags: firefox, display-resolution, touchscreen, scaling, dpi

If you are using a high DPI Display with a resolution of 3200x1600 px you can adjust Unity with a [System wide Menu and titlebar scaling](https://askubuntu.com/a/472266/34298) But Firefox is not really ready for this: All pages and the Icons stay tiny.

[multiplication of system font increase and browser font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783899/why-are-all-html-form-elements-huge-with-a-system-wide-font-scale-factor-2-0) increase makes system controls (combobox, lists, drop down lists) extremely big on many websites, where the form elements are affected by the scaling two times, so all form elements are huge (4x).

emails in Thunderbird are displayed tiny, so you have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> all the time

How can I adjust Firefox and Thunderbird, so everything will look normal?

Comment: Firefox is now supposed to pick up the scaling factor automatically. But somehow there's a bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1214470 that makes it round the value to the nearest integer, so one would still need to manually specify `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

1. Install my Firefox-addon [Zoom Menu Elements](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/zoom-menu-elements/) (or install this file from source on [github](https://github.com/rubo77/devPixelsPerPx-Toggle)).
   *Alternative: you can manually open a new tab `about:config` in Firefox and search for `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` set this value to `2` or `1.5` as you wish to adjust the size of the Firefox icons
   ([source](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/962588), [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1333158))*
2. Install the Firefox-addon [Fix for zoomed default-font](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/fix-for-zoomed-default-font/) to fix some issues with **huge form elements** on some pages (for ex. the login on reddit.com, ... see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783899/why-are-all-html-form-elements-huge-with-a-system-wide-font-scale-factor-2-0) )
3. Pinch-to-zoom works out of the box ([see here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1060212/34298)), for older versions the [grab and drag addon for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/grab-and-drag/) makes it possible to navigate the Internet by touch (disable it with the button [image: grab-and-drag-button] in the add-on-bar when using a mouse)
4. Additionally, (but not needed) install the Firefox addon [NoSquint](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/nosquint/) or  [Default Fullzoomlevel](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/default-fullzoom-level/) and chose in settings: default full **page zoom** level *120%*.

In **Thunderbird** you have to go for the *alternative* from *step 1* in the advanced configuration (although I prefer not to change the overall size but use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> instead, to adjust the size of the email window)

Comment: This is quite a pain when you switch back and forth between docking station (with 1920x1200) and the laptop screen (3000x1800). Would be nice is this was automatic.

Comment: I added a link to the now working Firefox-Addon that sets the zoom for all elements to Factor 2

Comment: the `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` is a great suggestion, thanx!

Answer (score 5):

I looks like Firefox 36.1 atleast, now picks up the scaling setting form Ubuntu. Its not dynamic - that is it reads the value when FF starts and its set at that until you restart FF. :)[image]

Comment: This should be the correct answer now. I also suspected I needed to restart the browser but thanks for confirming this with your answer. I restarted it immediately and it worked.

Comment: Though sometimes there are still problems with how Firefox interprets the system value (it rounds it to the nearest integer), for some reason, so one might still want to specify `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` manually. See the bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1214470

Answer (score 3):

[AutoHiDPI](https://github.com/ertug/autohidpi) is another good solution.

Comment: 2019 09: Not available anymore.

Comment: I edited the link.The add-on is old, but probably works well on Waterfox

Answer (score -6):

### Use chromium-browser instead

Firefox supports minimal touch-screen usage for some time now, and can be adapted via some add-ons, but Chrome supports:

- Pinch-to-zoom
- scrolling with one finger

out of the box.

To adapt the resolution, You only need the [system wide scaling](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472262/adapt-ubuntu-to-a-high-dpi-resolution-screen/472266#472266)

Comment: Is there a reason not to delete this question?

Comment: I think this is a valuable info for users, who wouldn't care to change the browser