# How to enable multitouch for touchpad and touchscreen on ThinkPad X1 Carbon 3rd gen?

Tags: 15.04, lenovo, thinkpad, multi-touch

How to enable multitouch for touchpad and touchscreen? I'm using Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid Vervet on a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon 3rd gen (Touch) 2015.

What does work:

- Fn+ buttons works out of the box – screen brightness, mute, volume adjustments, mic switch, Wi-Fi switch;
- TrackPoint with mouse buttons;
- Touchpad with 2 fingers multitouch (except pinch-to-zoom);
- Suspend;
- Keyboard backlight with 2 grades of intensity;
- WiFi, Bluetooth, WLAN;
- Touchscreen (multitouch doesn't work);
- Fingerprint reader.

What doesn't work:

- Touchpad multitouch with 3+ fingers;
- Touchscreen multitouch with 2+ fingers.

Answer (score 1):

Touchegg works for me -- however apparently not on Firefox or Chrome, only on **Chromium**, do the multi-touch gestures work for me (out-of-the-box).

On Chromium, I can one-finger drag (on-screen touch, not touchpad), two finger scroll (touchpad), pinch and zoom (on-screen touch).

See: Firefox bug, https://askubuntu.com/a/664898/67349

To fix chrome, I had to follow both answers at [Chrome + Touchscreen + Unity (14.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471513/chrome-touchscreen-unity-14-04)

First,

- Navigate to `chrome://flags/#touch-events` and
- set `Enable touch events Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS` to enabled.
- I also set "Enable pinch scale. Windows, Linux, Chrome OS" to enabled (instead of default).

Second, I needed to start google chrome and tell it which device.

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
$ google chrome --touch-devices=2
```

**My Setup**

- ubuntu 14.04
- lenovo 2nd gen x1.
- Chromium: Version 43.0.2357.130 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)
- Chrome: Version 43.0.2357.134 (64-bit)
- Firefox: 40.0

My `~/.config/touchegg/touchegg.conf` if it's useful:
http://pastebin.com/qGexA1gB