# How to enable touchscreen scrolling in FireFox?

Tags: firefox, touchscreen

I have noticed that touchscreen doesn't work in FireFox on Ubuntu 16 desktop (on a touchscreen laptop), which is a major bummer as I am a FireFox guy and the browser is 90% of what I use my personal computer for. Note that it works on non-linux FireFox and it works in Chrome/Chromium on Ubuntu.

I have done some research on this and found a lot of people with the same complaint 2 - 3 years back. In those cases the consensus was typically that FireFox just lacked some necessary technology to support this (some say GTK 3, others said something else). However they claimed that this issue was already fixed in the pre-released FF v50. Now FF 50 is out and I'm running it but it still doesn't work.

Is there something I can add, an Alpha / Beta / Dev / Nightly version I can use, or something I can do to Ubuntu itself to get this to work?

Comment: Which one 16.04 or 16.10?

Comment: @RolandiXor 16.04

Comment: Related bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1268599

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/868076/25639 for how to enable it

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This worked for me (firefox 57.0.4, Arch Linux):

1. open `about:config` in firefox to set `dom.w3c_touch_events.enabled=1` (default is 2).
2. edit `/etc/security/pam_env.conf` and add `MOZ_USE_XINPUT2 DEFAULT=1`
3. reboot and restart firefox

(see also [How can I get Firefox to recognize multitouch gestures on a touch screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536663/how-can-i-get-firefox-to-recognize-multitouch-gestures-on-a-touch-screen/868076#868076) )

Comment: didn't need to edit `about:config`, setting the environment variable was enough. On FF60.

Comment: this works except you want to disable the gestures to zoom as well. it's annoying to use 2-finger scroll and while you're scrolling it zooms in/out on the content. You can do this by adding `-disable` to the end of the values for `browser.gesture.pinch.in` and `browser.gesture.pinch.out`  for example `cmd_fullZoomReduce-disable`

Comment: The default dom.w3c_touch_events.enabled value of 2 seems to work just fine (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and FF 80.0.1)

Comment: no need for reboot, just log out an in again

Answer (score 43):

Found this solution elsewhere: if I start firefox from the command line with

```
env MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1 firefox
```

then touchscreen scrolling works for me. To avoid having to start firefox from the command line, you can edit the Unity app launcher exec code to include this. Default `.desktop` resides in `/usr/share/applications` but we'll copy it over to our home folder so that the changes we make are immune to be overriden by the package manager on update.

```
cp /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop
```

find the `Exec` line in the `[Desktop Entry]` section and change it to

```
Exec=env MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1 firefox %u
```

Change the other exec lines too, if you feel like it. Those affect the options in the right-click menu.

***EDIT:***
At some point this stopped working (I think because of an extension I installed). To fix it, I had to go to `about:config` in the browser, right-click, add a new boolean `browser.tabs.remote.force-enable` set to true. Warning: this is not recommended and could break stuff.

Adding a comment from Jeff G, you may also need to go to `about:config`and set `dom.w3c_touch_events.enabled = 1`.

Comment: In conjunction with XINPUT2=1, you might also need to go to `about:config` to set `dom.w3c_touch_events.enabled=1` (default was 2). In my experience this enabled two-finger scrolling, while one finger still selects text.

Comment: Note that you need to make sure you have a thing called e10s enabled. To find out if you do, open `about:support` and look for 'Multiprocess Windows'.

Comment: There's also an (admittedly pretty stupid) alternate way to handle setting `MOZ_USE_XINPUT2` - just add `MOZ_USE_XINPUT2 DEFAULT=1` to `/etc/security/pam_env.conf` and then never worry about it again (probably)

Comment: This worked without further modification for me on Firefox 57. Great!

Comment: @JeffG This doesn't work for me.  I put MOZ_USE_XINPUT2 DEFAULT=1 in the /etc/security/pam_env.conf.  No matter which touch_events value I pick (1 or 2), one finger is always scrolling. On FF68

Comment: Note that you have to close all running Firefox instances before launching Firefox again with this envvar. And note also that the `env` is unnecessary, it's just an envvar and you can just run `MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1 firefox`.

Comment: I would strongly recommend to never change package-managed files like the launchers in `/usr/share/applications/*.desktop`, because not only do they affect all users on the system and require root rights to change, they will also most likely get reverted again on the next software update. Also launching GUI apps as root like `sudo gedit` is bad because it easily messes up ownership of files in your home directory (e.g. caches, settings of that application) and breaks it when you try to use it normally again.

Comment: You should instead of this all place a copy of the .desktop file in your user's `~/.local/share/applications/` folder and change it to your liking in there, as regular user without sudo.

Comment: Doesn't work with Firefox 76.0.1 under Ubuntu 20.04... I actually get errors when starting Firefox now (it works, but gives me an error every time it starts).

Answer (score 4):

I found a browser plugin called [Grab and Drag](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/grab-and-drag/) which adds this functionality to FireFox.

Comment: Do you mean [this add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/grab-and-drag/)?

Comment: @PabloBianchi Yep that's the one

Comment: Grab and Drag appears to be designed for touch-only or pen-only computers. If you'd still like to use the mouse to select text etc., it's rather too drastic a solution. The `MOZ_USE_XINPUT2` works great, enabling kinetic scrolling, fling and drag-to-scroll.

Comment: @LeifArneStorset Seems to work for me, but I'll definitely check out the other solution as well, thanks

Comment: The add-on's page seems to be deleted =(

Answer (score 3):

### Firefox on Ubuntu 22.04 (Wayland)

To enable touchscreen finger scrolling in Firefox on Ubuntu 22.04 under Wayland display server you can enable Firefox Wayland support with the environment variable `MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND`.

Test from terminal with the following (close Firefox first):

```
MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1 firefox
```

To permanently set this, add to your profile settings:

```
echo "export MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1" >> ~/.profile
```

This environment variable should be the default on 22.10 onwards so not needed

Answer (score 2):

Found (yet) another Firefox add-on that lets you do that. Hope this one remains available for longer than the other two suggested.

[ScrollAnywhere](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scroll_anywhere/?src=search)

Once added, you have to go to Options > General and check the "Left button" box. I works for me on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Firefox 78.0.1 (64-bit)

Comment: July 31, 2020-- This is the only plugin that seems to exist and it works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Install the "Drag to Scroll" plugin. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/drag_scroll/

Comment: The add-on's page seems to be deleted =(