# HP Envy x360 Ryzen 5 - status of known issues

Tags: kernel, hp, touchscreen, amdgpu, display-rotation

There have been numerous issues getting the Envy x360 with Ryzen 5 to cooperate with Ubuntu. Several issues have been solved, and several remain.

I am currently running Ubuntu 18.04 with Linux kernel 4.18rc1. I am using the most up-to-date set up possible as the amdgpu drivers seem to be getting regular updates in the latest kernels.

Issue 1:
Log in.
The desktop only loads using Wayland. Default or Unity immediately returns me to the log in screen. Unity was working previously using Ubuntu 16.04 and kernels 4.15-4.17. I'm not sure if this is a Wayland issue or not, but the screen is a bit flickery in Firefox, and there are other signs of minor graphical issues following log in. It would be ideal for all of the display options to be available.

Issue 2:
Random crashes.
The entire system locks up and requires a hard reset using the power button. This happens frequently enough to be a major problem. Likely related to the graphics drivers? I turned hardware acceleration in Firefox off, but it can be hard to tell if the problem is solved, because sometimes it doesn't freeze for hours (while other times it freezes after a few minutes).

Issue 3:
Screen rotation.
Rotating the screen 90 degrees leads to a blank screen. Rotating back restores the screen. Rotating 180 degrees leads to an upside down screen (i.e. not possible to use in tent mode). Flipping the screen into tablet mode does disable the mouse and keyboard properly.

Issue 4:
Touch screen does not work.
This issue seems to have been figured out (https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=198715#c14)
Add I would also recommend then this fix to Firefox, if that is your browser of choice ([How to make touch-screen scrolling work in Firefox Quantum?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978226/how-to-make-touch-screen-scrolling-work-in-firefox-quantum/978701)).
However, it is very difficult for the average user to implement, and needs to be re-done each time there is a kernel update (which I install in the hopes that it fixes the random crashing issue). I also may have made some errors when I tried it, because the OS loaded slower and sometimes failed to load, but I can confirm that the touchscreen and pen input were working well after this. This needs a permanent solution.

Solved issues:
The wifi driver issue was fixed as far back as kernel 4.15.
Closing the lid to sleep seems to work properly on Ubuntu 18.04. This was not working as of Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.17.

Any help with any of these issues would be appreciated!

Comment: AskUbuntu is not a thread-based discussion or collaboration site. It's a simple Question and Answer format intended for common support issues. Each of the issues should be a separate Question...except the ones that are obvious bugs - you should report those to the appropriate bug tracker. Voting to close as Too Broad.

Comment: Most of these issues appear to be linked to the graphics drivers. If it is essentially one problem with a variety of symptoms, why not have all of the symptoms listed in one place?

Comment: Is there somewhere else keeping track of all these issues together ?  It's a pain rotating round different bug reports every week on the chance of a fix.

Comment: There are CPU issues, GPU and Touchscreen, these should all be tracked.

Comment: Can I ask you how much RAM do you see reported when you type `free` in your CLI? I have 8GB and free reports Total mem as: 6985.

Answer (score 1):

For freezes, check http://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196683, basically you need `idle=nomwait` kernel parameter to fix all hangs (from http://community.amd.com/thread/224000)

Comment: confirmed by https://community.amd.com/message/2869331#comment-2869331

Comment: It doesn't fix all hangs, only those from the CPU, I needed to set  pcie_aspm=off  as well.

Comment: hmm, I'm using also the kernel from https://cgit.freedesktop.org/~agd5f/linux/log/?h=amd-staging-drm-next, so `pcie_aspm=off` might not be needed in the latest code