# HP envy x360 - Ubuntu 18.04 - hardware issues

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, touchpad, hp, touchscreen

I have an HP ENVY x360 Convertible 15-bq1xx and I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 and keep it updated.

I have the following problems:

#### The touchscreen doesn't work

What I've found:
[touchscreen-on-hp-envy-x360-is-not-working-with-18-04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028946/touchscreen-on-hp-envy-x360-is-not-working-with-18-04)

**Question 1**:I'm a web developer and I sincerly have no idea of how to patch a kernel... Can anyone provide me some help on how [to do this](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=198715#c14)?

#### The computer freeze randomly

What I've found: [hp-envy-x360-ryzen-5-status-of-known-issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047374/hp-envy-x360-ryzen-5-status-of-known-issues)

**Question 2**: I've followed the answer of @brauliobo but when I run [Homestead](https://github.com/laravel/homestead) for my development environment and the computer goes in standby, it freeze again... I have to force the shut down by pressing the power button. It may be some wrong BIOS configuration? or I have to configure in another way the VirtualBox VM's I run for development?

#### The touchpad sometimes doesn't work

I've found nothing about this problem.... Googled a few... but the results I've found don't talk about HP computers...

**Question 3**: Sometimes when I log in, the touchpad doesn't respond... The coursor doesn't move and both left and right click aren't working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm all issues above in 18.10 using 4.18.0-10-generic, amd_gpu and mesa 18.2.2.

When I have a soft lockup instead of hitting the power button I press and hold

```
    ALT + Print Screen and R, then, S, then, E, then, I, then, N, then, U, then, B.
```

That reboots the OS a little more gracefully then the power button and should avoid a fsck if something is still writing, as with these lockups I notice that sometimes the hard drive light still going.

Otherwise I'm just going to wait until 19.04, when hopefully the remainder of the bugs are resolved, or use uuku to upgrade the kernel if I ever get around to it.

Comment: I didn't know about this combination.... Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: IIGala, I also found from reading phoronix that the 4.19 kernel has a lot of updates specifically for AMD, Vega and Raven Ridge. Some of the reporting and comments from these articles users are talking about increased stability. Either we can wait for 19.04 or us uuku to upgrade to later kernels and grab updated mesa files. Here's the most recent article, there's significant amount of reporting if you search their archives. https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Polaris-12-Vega-12-AMDKFD

Comment: I've installed ukuu and runned `sudo ukuu --install-latest`, now I'm running kernel 4.19.1-041901-generic, let's see what happens!

Comment: Let me know if the touchscreen works? Seen here someone with a similar laptop and using Fedora says that it's now working. https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=198715#c95

Comment: Also, I'm on 18.10 using the proposed and backports channels and I can confirm that the stability is much improved after a complete reinstall.

Comment: And also, I noticed the mouse touchpad is flaky, so when I went to the System Settings panel to try to change touch settings I noticed it was greyed out. I found on this website that you can install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics driver which is older and which should afford better controls so that you're not double tapping stuff all the time. https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/7qhyft/under_touchpad_settings_certain_options_are/

Comment: Tested the xserver-xorg-input-synaptics driver and it seems to solve a lot of the problems. Sometimes when I would boot, System Control would say that no touchpad was detected. Resetting the USB didn't work, so it was definitely a problem with the driver. If it doesn't work to solve that problem I'll let you know. I did read something somewhere about how the current driver libinput has ceased development so probably going back to a working driver is better.

Comment: Just installed 19.04 and the touchscreen is working, but I had to remove the xserver-xorg-input-synaptics driver

Comment: I've finally upgraded to 19.04... But with kernel 5.0 the system doesn't boot... I have to run 4.19, any suggestions?

Comment: this may be a little late but answered in this askubuntu:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135590/amdgpu-driver-refuses-to-load-on-19-04  the answer that @bbayles provides "Removing /lib/firmware/amdgpu/raven_dmcu.bin and running sudo update-initramfs -u -k all solved this problem."

Comment: Also, in 19.10 if during upgrade the system reboots on its own and you get a kernel panic on boot, then you may need to go to the rescue menu and run a root prompt, get the network connected to the laptop by using an external ethernet dongle connect it run "ip addr" find the ethernet adapter run "ip link set dev <ethernet name like eth0 or etx and mac> down" and then "dhclient <ethernet name as before> and then run "sudo dpkg --configure -a" to get the system to boot. I notice that the system locks up less with 19.10. It always seems to lock up when libra office is open for a while.