# amdgpu driver refuses to load on 19.04

Tags: amdgpu, 19.04

I have an HP x360 laptop with Ryzen 5 2500U and Raven Ridge graphics. This was working nicely with 18.10 on the 4.18.0-17 kernel, but stopped working properly after an upgrade to 19.04.

After the upgrade the system refused to finish booting - blank screen after the GRUB menu. I was able to get it to boot by adding `nomodeset` in GRUB. However, this prevents my second monitor from being detected.

I was also able to get the system to boot with the 19.04 kernel by blacklisting the `amdgpu` module. This of course also prevents my second monitor from working.

When I use the 4.18.0-17 kernel again, everything still works great. Is there anything I can do to make the 5.0 kernel work?

System details (running on 4.18.0-17):

```
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: AMD Ryzen 5 2500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx bits: 64 
           type: MT MCP arch: Zen L2 cache: 2048 KiB 
           flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm bogomips: 31940 
           Speed: 1369 MHz min/max: 1600/2000 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1452 2: 1434 3: 1371 4: 1474 
           5: 1430 6: 1369 7: 1400 8: 1371 
Graphics:  Device-1: AMD Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] 
           vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: amdgpu v: kernel bus ID: 03:00.0 
           Display: server: X.Org 1.20.4 driver: ati,fbdev unloaded: modesetting,radeon,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz, 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: AMD RAVEN (DRM 3.26.0 4.18.0-17-generic LLVM 8.0.0) v: 4.5 Mesa 19.0.2 
           direct render: Yes
```

Answer (score 4):

Removing `/lib/firmware/amdgpu/raven_dmcu.bin` and running `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because my reputation won't allow comments, I would like to say the solution bbayles provided worked for me as well upon an upgrade from 18.10 to 19.04. During my upgrade it crashed right before the step that starts to clean the packages installed.

Because I couldn't remember how to get the grub menu to display because of the video issue, I had to make a Kubuntu ISO USB with Rufus, and have it inserted at boot and try to boot from it at least once, then reboot. The grub menu showed up after. ESC and Shift weren't working for me before.

I was able to run his solution as well as connect it to a network and run the commands:
    dpkg --configure -a
    apt update
    apt -f install
    apt -m install
    apt dist-upgrade
    apt autoremove
    apt clean

I didn't reinstall the desktop but there were other various fixes like resetting the clock, plasma search, and reconfiguring the packages.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with Ubuntu 19.04 disco dingo on a HP Envy Ryzen 5 Vega. amdgpu issues caused 100+ hours of frustration, with kernel patches that locked up a lot but at least got a non blank screen, and with `nomodeset` in `grub` needed with the new Ubuntu install, which 19.04 is at least much more stable, but with no external monitor, no ability to change screen resolution, no rotations etc.

AMD response was to contact HP or Ubuntu - disappointing. I asked them to send your solution to their 'Linux team' -  if they have one :-\

(slightly off topic but helpful) - default `grub` Ubuntu menu did not show the grub boot menu (to select safe mode, or press <kbd>e</kbd> for temporary changes like nomodeset) - the solution was to set timeouts in `/etc/boot/grub.cfg` -  but be warned, a `grub-update` will change them to =0 again, so that needs to be done after any grub update or it goes straight to a blank screen again (unless `nomodeset` is in `grub`). pressing <kbd>esc</kbd> only got me to the `grub` terminal prompt.

And perchance newbies read this (there is little info on my searches let alone this solution) ...  to edit those files boot with live Ubuntu... make a directory, look in `/dev` for your Ubuntu partition, mount it as `sudo mount /dev/<partition name>` (edit : mount first before looking in `/dev`), `cd` to the directory, and edit your `/etc/boot/grub.cfg` file to set that timeout.