# 19.10 Ubuntu stops at boot screen when using NVIDIA proprietary driver

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, 19.10

I use Ubuntu 19.10 with GNOME3. Intel i5 CPU, 6GB RAM, a 1 TB HDD, and two display adapters: Intel's UHD 620 and an [NVIDIA GeForce mx130](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/nvidia-geforce-mx130). Secure Boot is disabled.

One day when I boot up my computer boot screen hanged and the system was unresponsive. Pressing escape button didn't show the boot info in the terminal and the dot animation is also stopped. After searching for some solutions I booted into recovery mode and uninstalled the NVIDIA driver. Then it worked but now my computer uses open-source free driver nouveau which is slower.

I recently switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu. When I was using windows 10 it used Intel UHD as the primary GPU, with NVIDIA GPU used for gaming.
Until yesterday night everything was good before I turned on my laptop.

I tried,

---

- completely removing Nvidia nad installing latest drivers in multiple ways(apt && installer provided by website)
- adding `nomodeset` in grub instructions
- disabling Wayland in gnome3

---

However, I added the `coolbits` option in the Nvidia `.conf` file before the night this happened.

Comment: Disable Secure boot in BIOS.

Comment: @Pilot6 It's disabled. I mentioned it on the question.

Comment: Try removing the coolbits option...

Comment: Choose safe graphic option and try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1203300/ubuntu-19-10-freezing-on-dell-vostro-14-5490/1209167#1209167

Comment: @heynnema I removed coolbits option. But it stil don't work