# One finger scrolling (touchscreen) in Firefox

Tags: firefox, thinkpad, touchscreen, scrolling

I try to enable one finger scrolling in firefox ( it's more comfortable to scroll like that with a touchscreen). The default fedora version of firefox and chromium work like that.

I tried to launch firefox with the option MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1 but it doesn't work..
Can you help me ??

Comment: It would help a little if you explain how you are trying to use `MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1`, as in where did you place this command?

Answer (score 6):

I had similar issues with the HP Pavilion x360.
I found that MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1 only works in Wayland, not Xorg.
Furthermore, to make it a permanent solution I needed to follow these steps:

1. open `about:config` in firefox to set `dom.w3c_touch_events.enabled=1` (default is 2).
2. edit `/etc/security/pam_env.conf` and add `MOZ_USE_XINPUT2 DEFAULT=1`
3. reboot and restart firefox

See https://askubuntu.com/a/994483/799524

Comment: Worked for me in Mint 20.2 (Ubuntu 20.04 base).

Answer (score 1):

I just might have the solution for you.

I was facing the exact same issue with Firefox where I could only scroll with two-fingers and single finger selected text.

After a lot of searching I found this [Gentoo Wacom page](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Wacom#Xinput2_multitouch) mentioning that the Wacom driver has gesture emulation that causes a problem with Firefox and my Thinkpad X1 Yoga has a Wacom touchscreen.

The fix is to turn off the Wacom gesture setting by creating the following file:

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-wacom.conf
```

With this configuration:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Wacom class"
    MatchProduct "Wacom|WACOM|Hanwang|PTK-540WL|ISDv4|ISD-V4|ISDV4"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"

    Driver "wacom"
    Option "Gesture" "off"
EndSection
```

Resart and enjoy :)

Comment: Any idea if this can be tweaked to work for the stylus as well - it's still selecting text instead of scrolling?

Comment: So a bit of searching didn't turn up anything using wacom driver but found mention of [easystroke]https://github.com/thjaeger/easystroke/wiki) to map pen button to enable scrolling in browser etc. 

Source: https://sandeel.github.io/wacom-tablet-scrolling-in-linux.html

Answer (score 0):

**found a solution** based on the wacom config file *Cas* mentioned, whose solution ultimately didnt work for me on my yoga 7.
however, based on this i found, in the KDE system control panel, under *input devices* the section *graphic tablets*. there is a register card *touch* with a checkbox *enable gestures* which is activated by default. after disabling it, gestures worked again in firefox. seems they enabled it from 21.10 to 22.04.
and yes, as also mentioned by *Cas*, when this checkbox remains enabled, i have to scroll with two fingers in firefox. i didnt know that.

[checkbox][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fpTP.png