# Which drivers should I install for Stylus and Touchscreen on Lenovo Yoga C740?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, lenovo, touchscreen, stylus

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on Lenovo Yoga C740, and scrolling on Firefox is not possible with the Pen and when touching. I also tried to use One Note online, and I can't write with the Pen, it can only select.

Can you please help me to the install the necessary drivers ? Thank you.

xinput --list

```
    ⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:01 04F3:3113 Touchpad            id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom HID 51EF Pen stylus                 id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom HID 51EF Finger touch               id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom HID 51EF Pen eraser                 id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: AFAIK there are no drivers to be installed. Regarding Firefox scrolling, your issue might be solved with this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/886914/27968

Comment: Thank you, I will try that, but also the Stylus and Touch wont respond on scrolling in other Programs, so I think there should be something to configuree

Comment: Hello! Do you also suffer from touchpad jittering issues when charging? Have you solved those?

Comment: No I was not having these issues.. Using Ubuntu 20.04 now is much better than 18.04